# RegularExpressionValidator error message

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, file-upload

I'm trying to add a check for file types to a file upload form:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="FileUpLoadValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Upload .doc, .pdf or .xls files only." ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.xls|.XLS|.pdf|.PDF|.doc|.DOC)$" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Before adding the `RegularExpressionValidator` any file type could be uploaded.

After adding it, any file type can still be uploaded.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Check with syntax 'multiple' in fileupload control.

Comment: With or without `multiple` (which allows multiple file upload) I get the same result. I'll remove it for clarity.

Comment: @Robert have u tried my logic dear..

Comment: Yes, without any luck.

Comment: @Robert check my answer please,hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use This Logic as well

```
^.*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|doc|DOC|pdf|PDF)$
```

You are using `dot` and `dot is a special character`. 
There is a [tool](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) for checking your `Regular Expression`.
You may add other file `Extension` as well.

Try this also

```
^([a-zA-Z].*|[1-9].*)\.(((p|P)(d|D)(f|F))|((d|D)(o|O)(c|C)))$
```

**Code Behind**

For that you need to have a `Button` and on it's `OnClick` event you have to check `extension1` of file first like

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
            // Get the name of the file to upload.
            string fileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName);
            // Get the extension of the uploaded file.
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            // Allow only files with .doc or .xls or .pdf extensions
            // to be uploaded.
            if ((extension == ".pdf") || (extension == ".xls") || (extension == ".doc"))
            {
            //upload accordingly
            }
            else 
            {
             // Show message
            }
}
```

Hope it works

Comment: I tried that with a `.htm` file and unfortunately it still uploaded.

Comment: is it necessary to complete that task by `Regular Expresion Validator` only.i have an another way but that is by coding.

Comment: No, it was just the only way I was aware of. If you have another solution that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Only JPG/jpg file allowed!" 
                    ControlToValidate="ctlFileUpload" 
                    ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w](.)*))+(\.jpg|\.JPG)$" 
                    Width="510px" CssClass="Validator"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

//-----or

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Only JPG/jpg file allowed!" 
                    ControlToValidate="ctlFileUpload" 
                    ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpg|.JPG)$" 
                    Width="510px" CssClass="Validator"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

//-------or

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="imgValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="imgUpload"
                ErrorMessage="*JPG/JPEG/GIF files only" ValidationExpression="^.+\.(([jJ][pP][eE]?[gG])|([gG][iI][fF]))$" />
```

or try this to allow user to upload txt file

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="FileUpLoadValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only text files!"
                ValidationExpression=".*(\.txt|\.TXT)$" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" Display="None">
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following and the page hangs on clicking upload: `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="FileUpLoadValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Upload Excel files only." ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w](.)*))+(\.xls|\.XLS)$"  ControlToValidate="FileUpload1">`

Comment: use this expression '^.*\.xls[xm]?$'